# Is there a way or gem to obfuscate javascript function names with Rails 3.2 on push to Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline, obfuscation

We have a rails 3.2 app running on Heroku. In development we don't compile assets, in production on Heroku we do "rake assets:precompile" (on push).

Much of our frontend business logic is in Javascript and as such we'd like to obfuscate variable names which, to my knowledge, the rails asset pipeline yui compressor cannot do.

Is there a smart "automatic-on-push-to-Heroku" (I guess a gem would be preferable) way to do this?

Thanks :-)

Comment: Isn't Heroku doing this for you automatically? Or maybe your stack isn't Cedar?

Comment: They don't (but the do the asset precompilation automatically, but that doesn't obfuscate function names - variables are obfuscated with the yui compressor setting in Rails). Stack is Cedar.

Comment: Then you can stick to `var doSomething = function() { ... }`-way of defining functions (which is what CoffeScript produces).

Comment: @jdoe Seems a good way to do it. Please submti as answer and I'll accept :-)  Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @jdoe stated in a comment above: "Then you can stick to var doSomething = function() { ... }-way of defining functions (which is what CoffeScript produces)."

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [uglifier gem](https://github.com/lautis/uglifier) which is a wrapper for UglifyJS... It can mangle your js.. obfuscation has many techniques

see uglifyjs demo [here](http://lisperator.net/uglifyjs/#demo)

As you can see, variable names are obfuscated

Comment: Thanks but what I want to do is obfuscate *function* names and variables, not only variables. @jdoe has stated a good solution above (as long as uglifier cannot do it automatically) - have awaited him to submit as answer so I could mark the question as answered, but have copy-pasted the solution now to not leave it open.

Comment: uglifier can mangle function names.. it is in their docs.. https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2#mangler-options and https://github.com/lautis/uglifier#usage

Comment: I'd love if that's the case, but how I read it (and how it works out of the box), it can only compress functions, not mangle their names. Can you point me to the mangling of functions in the documentation, please?

Comment: did you find it in the docs? I'd love to be able to mangle function names through uglifyjs.